# Building for iOS Simulator, but the linked and embedded framework 'abc.framework' was built for iOS

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, frameworks, xcode12.5

I am using third party framework which is working fine on real device but when I am running it on simulator, I am getting error. I do understand that this framework was build for iPhones. But currently I wanna run my application having this framework in my project on simulator.

AIM : I want this framework to be in my project but I do not care if it is not working in simulator, is there any way that I can bypass this framework at compile time or is there any way that I can add required architecture(x86_64) so I can at least run my app on simulator.

I am clearly able to see supported architectures:

```
Architectures in the fat file: /Users/Desktop/abc.framework/abc are: armv7 arm64
```

Comment: the framework doesnt support simulators. maybe they have another version that does?

Comment: @Scriptable no they do not have any version for simulator, they only provide framework for device. I just want my app to run so that I do not have to remove framework every time before running my app on simulator. I am just wondering if I can bypass it at compile time.

Comment: Most likely the framework is not correctly built (as it _should_ include simulator environment), unless there's a specific reason why this framework cannot run on simulators (for example if it's a hardware-specific one). You can have 2 targets for example: one - the actual app, and the other - dev build, which excludes that framework. And then in code control it with `#if targetEnvironment(simulator)`